# Why two nodes of es return different results

Tags: elasticsearch

There are three nodes of my es, and the target index has 1 shard and 1 replica.
The api of `_cat/shards` return :

```
article-test                    0 p STARTED    210236  23.8gb 10.0.2.37  node-03
article-test                    0 r STARTED    210236  23.8gb 10.0.2.182 node-01
```

But, when I want to search something from this index, the `node-01` would not return data, but the `node-03` returns the correct results.

I have troubled this problem for a long time, and can`t find some solution from other websites.
So, can anyone help me...
The query is belowed.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {

            "must": [
              {"term": {
                "qqq": {
                  "value": true
                }
              }},
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
              "query": "query",
              "type": "best_fields", 
              "fields": ["xx^3", "yy", "zz"],
              "operator": "and", "analyzer": "ik_smart"}
            }, {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "query", 
                "type": "phrase", 
                "fields": ["xx^3", "yy", "zz"], 
                "operator": "and", 
                "analyzer": "ik_smart", 
                "boost": 3}
            }, {
              "term": {
                "xx.keyword": {
                  "value": "query"}
              }
            }, {
              "term": {
                "aaa.keyword": {
                  "value": "query"}
              }
            }]
                }
              }
            ]
        }
      }, 
            "functions": [
              {
                "gauss": {
                  "aaa": {
                    "origin": "2019-12-19", 
                    "scale": "50d", 
                    "offset": "90d", 
                    "decay": 0.4}
                }
              }, {
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {"match": {"xxx": true}}, 
                      {"match": {"yyy": 1}}]}}, 
                      "weight": 5}
                      ]
    }
  }, 
  "from": 0, 
  "size": 10, 
  "_source": ["xx", "yy", "zz"], 
  "sort": {"_score": {"order": "desc"}}, 
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": ["<strong>"], 
    "post_tags": ["</strong>"], 
    "fields": {"xx": {}, "yy": {}, "zz": {}}
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "would not return any data"?  Do you mean that you run the same query multiple times and it returns different results?

Comment: Yes. I run the same query multiple times and two nodes return differenet results.